# Анимация появления и скрытия View

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Есть некоторая `View`, появление и скрытие которой необходимо анимировать.

Изначально `View` находится в скрытом состоянии. По нажатию на кнопку необходимо чтобы `View` выезжала снизу вверх в нижний правый угол экрана (с определенными отступами справа и снизу в видимом состоянии).

По второму нажатию необходимо реализовать скрытие: заезжание `View` с видимой позиции за пределы экрана вниз.

Я могу это реализовать, но только в том случае, если изначально `View` находится в видимом состоянии.

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private boolean mIsImageViewHided = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mIsImageViewHided = !mIsImageViewHided;
                mButton.setText(mIsImageViewHided ? "Show" : "Hide");
                if (mIsImageViewHided) {
                    hideView(mImageView);
                } else {
                    showView(mImageView);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void hideView(View view) {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, view.getHeight() + getViewBottomMargin(mImageView));
        translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        translateAnimation.setDuration(100);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    }

    private void showView(View view) {
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, view.getHeight() + getViewBottomMargin(mImageView), 0);
        translateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        translateAnimation.setDuration(100);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        view.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
    }

    private float getViewBottomMargin(View view) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        return layoutParams.bottomMargin;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Show"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать то, что я хочу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете смещение в анимации картинки, чтобы добиться смещения от изначальной позиции , нужно imageView.setX() , и так же для Y координаты,  начальные координаты 0.0 находятся в верхнем левом углу. По окончании анимации , элемент возвращается в начальное положение( по умолчанию)